# How to fine tune BERT to summarize articles

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, word2vec, summarization

I'm learning nlp, and as a study project, i'm trying to face the [news summarization dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/sunnysai12345/news-summary), using BERT.

The dataset is simple (in the news_summary_more.csv) - it has **articles** and **headlines** columns.

What I think, is to use the **articles** as feature (X), and **headlines** as target (Y).

My question is how do I measure success in the fine-tuning, so the model will learn?

The model prediction will almost never be the same the the real target (y != ^y), because there are so many options to summarize the articles, and almost 100% of the cases the model will have somewhat different summarization than the real headline.

Example:

```
Team A won the game against team B
```

is different from:

```
Team A is victorious against team B on the game
```

Although both has pretty much the same meaning.

So how can I test if the model is getting close to the real target? (maybe somehow using MSE)

Answer (score 0):

f1_score would the right measure for such a dataset